# How to flush SQLite3 database changes to disk?

Tags: linux, sqlite, debian

My application is running on a portable Debian (5 and 8) computer. This computer may lose power at unpredictable times. The application is frequently updating a specific SQLite3 database, and flushing to disk immediately, using a `sync()` command. This is done to avoid corruption of the database, which would happen in the power disappears before the changes are fully written to disk.

This has been working nicely, but now the problem is that the `sync()` command flushes ALL buffered changes to disk, for all open files. This causes a slowdown in other parts of the system. One possible solution is to only flush critical file changes, such as this specific database file. But the question is; how can I do that? I have no access to file descriptors, and I can't find any SQLite3 functions that does this for me. Any ideas?

Comment: Eh, sqlite3 commits have all the syncing they need already.

Comment: On all systems? That doesn't quite fit my observations. I get corrupt databases if I don't call the sync() after committing changes.

Comment: https://www.sqlite.org/atomiccommit.html

Comment: You might find something here too: https://www.sqlite.org/howtocorrupt.html

Comment: I removed the global flush now, which was associated with syncing the database file. Instead I added specific flushes for the other files that needs to be in sync with the physical harddrive. After a bunch of testing, I still am not able to corrupt the database. So it seems you are completely correct. Thank you for your help!

Answer (score 0):

you can use file specific syncing. fsync() will be useful for this.

see https://www.sqlite.org/c3ref/db_cacheflush.html